# how to send data from chrome extension to ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, google-chrome-extension

I need to send a request from the chrome extension directly to the ios app and get a response. How to connect between the two applications in the same network?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to connect the backends of iOS applications and Chrome Extensions would be to use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), which has simple iOS, Web, and REST API setup for applications like this.